# How can I access string values in Results View where the number of results may vary?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, ienumerable

How can I access the `string` values in `IEnumerable` Results View, where the results may vary?

[image: Results View]

I am using a `foreach` loop to iterate through a `list`, and then grabbing the distinct values of `VehicleID`:

```
foreach (var trip in paidTrips) {
    var vehicleids = trip
        .Select(x => x.VehicleID)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
```

I know how to do this:

```
string n = vehicleids[0];
string o = vehicleids[1];
```

But that gives me an "Index was out of range"-exception if there's more than two items.

I am thinking it would be good to use a for loop to iterate through the indexes and create an array out of them? If so, how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
IEnumerable<string> vehicleIds=paidTrips
        .Select(x => x.VehicleID)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
        //or ToArray();
```

you can acces using foreach loop

```
foreach( var id in vehicleIds)
{
       Console.WriteLine(id);
}
```

or just using index

```
var vehicleId0 = vehicleids[0];
//or 
var vehicleId1=vehicleId[1];
```

or using linq

```
var vehicleId=vehicleIds.FirstOrDefault(x=> x=="1223");
```

Comment: Hello @Serge. This might be a different question.
I need to access the separate values and use them outside of the foreach loop.
I used your example, and then `string[] vehicleArr = vehicleIds.ToArray();`
How can I access this array outside of the foreach loop?

Comment: @OleM I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The debugger is fooling you. You are looking at a `DistinctIterator` that was added to a `Select` query. The values you're seeing in the debugger is the *raw* data *before* the `DistinctIterator` filters it. Since they both have the same value, after `Distinct` runs, you only have one value in the list, which is why `vehicleids[1]` fails. So the problem is that your result has *less* than two items, not *more*.

You can certainly access list items with an indexer, but the problem in this case is you *think* you have 2 values but in reality you only have 1. You can also use `for` or `foreach` to loop through when you don't know the number of elements (using `vehicleids.Count()` as the "stop" condition for the for loop.

Comment: Aha, that's interesting. Thank you.